# Regarding the update of gms-play-services appindexing to 10.2.0 in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I was trying to update my Google Play services app indexing to 10.2.0 and I updated the compile line in my dependencies of build.gradle [as shown in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbLNx.png) as compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:10.2.0" but I am facing an error as shown in the image as "Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:10.2.0".

I even tried the install repository link but it didn't work.

Comment: open your SDK manager and install Google Repository

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm facing the same issue

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue.

App indexing has moved from *Play Services* to *Firebase*.

You need to delete the line

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:10.2.0'
```

since this lib does not exist, you already have app indexing in your dependencies here:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:10.2.0'
```